# nvd3 multichart yaxis start from zero

Tags: nvd3.js

Is it possible in nvd3 multichart yaxis to start from zero and max be determined by the input data?

I tried chart.yDomain1([0,100]); but chart gets cut off at max of 100. I need the max to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

So you helped me figure out how to set the y axis range so I thought Id try and return the favour, even if it is six months later
I started with the source code from the multi-chart example
 https://github.com/nvd3-community/nvd3/blob/gh-pages/examples/multiChart.html

What you want to do is to calculate the max of your data and then use that within the `chart.yDomain1()` function.

Example fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/q72tzyaL/1/

```
var data = [{
        "key": "key",
        "type": "bar",
        "values": [
            { x: 2012, y: 40 }, 
            { x: 2013, y: 36 }
        ]
    }, {
        "key": "key",
        "type": "bar",
        "values": [
            { x: 2012, y: 40 }, 
            { x: 2013, y: 36 }
        ]   
    }];

// each item is an object from the array with an array of values
// get the values that we need from that array and then get the max of that
function getMax(item) {
    return d3.max(item.values.map(function(d){ return d.y; }));
}

// get the max. Pass in your data array and the function to get max
var max = d3.max(data, getMax);

nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.multiChart()
                    .margin({top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 50, left: 70})
                    .yDomain1([0, max]);

    d3.select('#chart1 svg')
      .datum(data)
      .transition().duration(500).call(chart);

   return chart;
});
```